# How to fix this error: The method toString() in the type Object is not applicable for the arguments?

Tags: java

I created an array of numbers. Now I want that array to be displayed in the output so I used `System.out.println`.

But if we do that, the array won't be shown so we have to convert the array into a string just before we display it. To do that, we could use `Arrays.toString()` function.

It's showing the following error:

> The method `toString()` in the type `Object` is not applicable for the arguments?

Below is the code I want to execute:

```
public class Arrays {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    int[] array1 = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
    System.out.println((Arrays.toString(array1);
  }
}
```

Comment: do you mean `array1` instead of `Arrays`?

Comment: Yeah, I meant that, now I've modified the code...Still doesn't work though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things:

- `Arrays.toString()` accepts an array as a parameter. Pass `array1` to the method
- Your class name `Arrays` is conflicting with the `java.util.Arrays` class. Either rename the class or use a direct path (demonstrated below).
- You are missing some ending brackets

Try this:

```java
public class Arrays {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    int[] array1 = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(array1));
  }
}
```

[Which prints](https://ideone.com/2VcNII):

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Alright, I tried what u just told and it worked. Also, the problem was with the name in the code I've written. After changing the class name and file name, it worked.

Comment: @SuperVillain Glad to help :)